# Search for pages with no text in a PDF

Tags: pdf, text, ocr, ghostscript

How would you proceed to search for "empty" pages in a pdf file? 
In the next step I want to convert those pages to .tiff using ghostscript. If it is possible to do everything with one command on a unix machine, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this depends in large part on what you mean by 'text' (from your subject line) or 'empty' pages (from your body text). Its entirely possible to have vector paths which reproduce the shape of text, or indeed images which reproduce character shapes.

Do you consider these to be 'text' ?

Or are you looking for pages which have no content at all (ie  empty) ? I can't imagine why you would want to render those to TIFF.....

For pages with no text (ie not using any of the PDF text operators) then I would use the text extraction device in Ghostscript. Any page whose output is empty from that device has no text on it.

You can then run Ghostscript on the PDF file and use the -sPageList switch to process just the pages you want, and select one of the TIFF devices in order to get TIFF output.

You can't do this in one pass (with an unodified Ghostscript), because you need the text extraction device to figure out which pages have text, and then the TIFF device to write the pages.

You *could* write a new device which output to TIFF, and if the text_begin() method of the device is ever called, it simply skips writing the page. That would do it in one pass, but it would mean writing a new device (99% of which is copy+paste of a tiff device) and rebuilding Ghostscript. You would also have to AGPL your code of course.

Comment: Sorry, I am talking about scanned documents. So no vectors. Everything that an OCR considers text, is text. And I want to extract every page that does not show text, but could be an image or stamp or is just white. 

Thank your for your answer, now I know on which devices I should focus on ghostscript (which is a bit hard to understand). 

For now I manually found the pages and extracted them with imagemagick, which was not too much work.